# Applying css on asp.net FileUpload Control's Browse Button only

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, css

I have a FileUpload Control like this

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileuploader" runat="server" />
```

Now I want to apply css only on the Browse button part

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Styling an `input` tag with `type="file"` requires a bit of work, browsers don't behave similarly when you try to style them unfortunately.

There are a few methods of doing so though:

- http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html
- http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/filestyle

Comment: second link is not found.

Answer (score 9):

This is possible you can change the `FileUpload` control using following code.

**Step 1**: Change FileUpload control with this code on aspx page

```
<label class="file-upload">
    <span><strong>Upload Image</strong></span>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" >
    </asp:FileUpload>
</label>
```

**Step 2**: now add below CSS code into your main CSS file

```
.file-upload {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: Arial;
    border: 1px solid #124d77;
    background: #007dc1;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-shadow: #000 1px 1px 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
}

.file-upload:hover {
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #0061a7), color-stop(1, #007dc1));
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0061a7 5%, #007dc1 100%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0061a7 5%, #007dc1 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0061a7 5%, #007dc1 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0061a7 5%, #007dc1 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0061a7 5%, #007dc1 100%);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0061a7', endColorstr='#007dc1',GradientType=0);
        background-color: #0061a7;
}

/* The button size */
.file-upload {
    height: 30px;
}

.file-upload, .file-upload span {
        width: 90px;
}

.file-upload input {
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            margin: 0;
            font-size: 11px;
            font-weight: bold;
            /* Loses tab index in webkit if width is set to 0 */
            opacity: 0;
            filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

.file-upload strong {
            font: normal 12px Tahoma,sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
}

.file-upload span {
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            display: inline-block;
            /* Adjust button text vertical alignment */
            padding-top: 5px;
}
```

It's done.

Comment: This answer helped me come up with a solution to my requirement. I simply needed an image to be used instead of the default "Choose File" button. I just wrapped the image and the fileupload control in a label as described here, but I got rid of most of the styling and had no need for the text styles. Thanks you very much! This is by far the best solution I came across!

Comment: This solution was very helpful. but i don't know why the design violates itself. Whenever i click on the button the text over the button moves up and it never aligns back to center http://tinypic.com/r/2646sdh/9

Comment: Thank you. I just got our mail with the attachment script working and fixing to add it to our site for the new update, and the color scheme you provided here with your CSS goodness is just what we needed. So, thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

apparently you cannot style them directly with CSS but you can "hack" a new style into them - read the following article for details

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html