# Editing a browse button

Tags: html, css

I have a browse button that I want to edit. Here is how I made it:

```
<input type = "file" id = "myBrowseButton" class = "BrowseButtons" name = "Browse"  />
```

The button looks like you regular browse button but I want it to look like this: 
[image]

I have been asking around and doing research, and from what I can tell the only (not incredibly long and time consuming) way to edit this would be to find some utility that will do it for me and mess around with that. Where would I be able to find said utility/ is there another (not extremely time consuming) way to edit this?

Comment: Check out some existing questions about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906039/applying-css-on-asp-net-fileupload-controls-browse-button-only/3906063#3906063

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've started doing all my form buttons (and many links for that matter) using Jquery's UI Button functionality.  With a relatively small grouping of files, it automatically rounds, styles, and improves functionality while the included Theme Roller system allows you to change styling with a simple, configurable download...or even allows switching on the fly.

Getting this look is as simple as adding: `class="fg-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all"`  These styles work on other elements too, so you can round divs, images, etc.

Here's a primer: http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/styling_buttons_and_toolbars_with_the_jquery_ui_css_framework/

Once you become familiar with ThemeRoller, it's even possible to use it to style other elements of your page/app.  I have one application that I've done entirely this way, so to re-theme the app for a different client I simply generate a new ThemeRoller theme.

Comment: JQuery UI doesnt seem to work for file upload controls, specifically the "browse..." button

Comment: @Fergie, perhaps you're missing something, I'm running it on ALL my file upload buttons, perhaps dozens of working examples.

Answer (score 1):

This is just little trick, maybe you can use.
I'm using a span to cover the file button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#button1").button();
        $("#button1").click(function() {
            $("#fileUpload1").click();
        });
    });
</script>
<span id="span1" style="overflow: hidden;width: 300px;white-space: nowrap; display: inline-block;">
    <input type="file" id="fileUpload1" name="fileUpload1" size="100" style="width: 400px;"/>
</span>
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Browse Custom 1"/>
```

This works for me, using Firefox & IE but not in Chrome, because the UI is different.

Second, when using a jQuery dialog with file upload in it, the width of file upload is changed back according to span width. So the trick is to set the width again after opening the dialog:

```
$("#button3").click(function() {
    $('#dialog1').dialog('open');
    $("#fileUpload2").width(1000);
    $("#span2").width(200);
    //$("#fileUpload2").css('margin-left', '300');
});


<div id="dialog1" style="display: none;">
<span id="span2" style="overflow: hidden;width: 300px;white-space: nowrap; display: inline-block;">
    <input type="file" id="fileUpload2" name="fileUpload2" size="100" style="width: 400px; margin-left: 300px;"/>
</span>
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Browse Custom 2"/>
```

This is just a trick, I don't think it works for everyone, sorry if can't help you all. A simple solution for a simple case.