# Change Button style in Fileupload control

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a Fileupload control on my Page. I want to change browse button's  style.

```
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fuAttachment" CssClass="mediumResolution required"
                                                size="50" Width="100%" />
```

how can I do that?

Comment: What about the style do you want to change? You'e already setting the CssClass which is where you can can apply CSS style.

Comment: check this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906039/applying-css-on-asp-net-fileupload-controls-browse-button-only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this using CSS. go to this link.

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2007/09/10/styling_file_inputs_with_css_and_the_dom