# How to replace the browser button with an image for the FileUpload control?

Tags: asp.net, image, file-upload

I have a FileUpload control in my page as following. It has a Browse... button by default. I would like to replace it with an ImageButton that has customized image. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

```
<td width="40%" valign="top" align="center">
                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
</td>
```

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Comment: It's a bit tricky, but this [article](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html) should get you started in the right direction. You can also do this in jQuery, as explained [here](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/filestyle).

Answer (score 2):

After searching all over, I finally came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31047057/2228227). Since I merely need to replace the default "Choose File" button with my image, I removed most of the styling and changed the markup to suit my needs.

I ended up with:

```
.file-upload {
  cursor: pointer;      
}

.file-upload input {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  /* Loses tab index in webkit if width is set to 0 */
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

```html
<label class="file-upload">
  <img src="../myimage.png" />
  <asp:FileUpload ID="myfile" runat="server" />
</label>
```

I hope this helps others looking for a similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

like Michael Leanos answer, but i made a change:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .file-upload 
    {
        cursor: pointer;      
    }

    .file-upload input 
    {
        /* the same icon width/heght */
        width:70px;
        height:70px;
        /* a z-index higher than the icon */
        z-index:999;
        /* less opcacity as possible */
        opacity: 0.01;        
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    }
</style>
```

/* on the icon more opacity as possible and a low z-index */

```
<label class="file-upload">
    <asp:FileUpload ID="up_Allegato" runat="server" type="file" accept="image/*" _capture="camera" Style="position: absolute; right: 100px; top: 150px; height: 70px; line-height: 19px;" />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="bt_Photo" runat="server" Visible="true" ImageUrl="images/action_edit24 x 200.png" OnClientClick="return false;" Style="position: absolute; right: 100px; top: 150px; height: 70px; line-height: 19px;z-index:6 ;opacity:100"/>
 </label>
```